# Angular dialog not opening up as a modal window

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and just trying to get a an dialog window to pop up and it is showing up BUT not as a modal window.

Here is some of my code

Inside 'app.module.ts'

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations"
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { MatCardModule } from "@angular/material";
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    QuadMergeSearchFormComponent,
    QuadMergeSearchResultsDialogComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    QuadMergeSearchResultsDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MembersideRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Inside 'quad-merge-search-form.component'

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

onSubmit(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(QuadMergeSearchResultsDialogComponent, 
    {
        width: '600px',
        height: '400px'
    });
}
```

Do I need to add anything to quad-merge-search-form.component.html?

Inside 'quad-merge-search-results-dialog.component'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quad-merge-search-results-dialog',
  templateUrl: './quad-merge-search-results-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quad-merge-search-results-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class QuadMergeSearchResultsDialogComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}
```

and

```
<p>
  quad-merge-search-results-dialog works!
</p>
```

Inside 'app.component.html' (does anything need to go in here?)

```
<site-header></site-header>
<div class="site-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<site-footer></site-footer>
```

When I run page and click on button, the dialog shows up BUT below `'<site-footer>'` tag.

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: Have you added the material CSS file / theme?

Comment: No, I do not think so.  The .scss files for both compnents are empty.  Where else would I look?

Comment: Take a look at [the docs for Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme), they should cover how to add a theme

Comment: Do I need a theme in order for a dialog to popup as a modal window?

Comment: Yes, otherwise no styles are being applied, so the CSS that styles the element as a modal doesn't exist.

Comment: I added this to 'app.component.scss' : @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

What else do I need to do at this point?

Comment: That guide suggests that you add that line to `styles.scss` instead...

Comment: Ok, I added '@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";' to styles.css and the modal window is still showing up at the bottom of the page (under the footer section).  Any idea?

Comment: Can you create a very basic StackBlitz that reproduces the issue please?

Comment: Actually it is working now, thanks for your help!!  I didn't add the .css file to the index.html page!!

'<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">'

Answer (score 3):

add this line

```
./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
```

to `angular.json` file in your app.

Be sure to restart ng serve to reload the angular.json file.